# SQL Server substring without upper bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the best way in SQL Server to do

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING('CATCH ME IF YOU CAN', 2, 10000)
    -- ATCH ME IF YOU CAN
```

with no upper bound?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `STUFF` instead ([STUFF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)):

```
SELECT STUFF('CATCH ME IF YOU CAN',1,1,'');
```

Here, `STUFF` replaces 1 character, from position 1 with the string `''`. The 2nd parameter is the start position, and the 3rd is the number of characters (from that position) to replace. The 4th is the replacement string.

So, as a further example, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT STUFF('2019-07-09 11:38:00',11,1,'T');
```

This replaces 1 character from position 11 with the character `'T'`, which returns `'2019-07-09T11:38:00'`, changing the above value to the ISO8601 format. As you can see, the length of the string to replace does not need to be the same length as the replacement string as well (in fact, the 3rd parameter can have a value of `0`, meaning that no characters are replaced and the "replacement" string is simply injected into the existing value).

Comment: SELECT STUFF('/KKBGC/CHBusinessUmsatz', 1,LEN('/KKBGC'),'')  returns /CHBusinessUmsatz

Comment: @LudovicAubert Why do you have a `LEN` function in there? What is your comment trying to say?

Comment: It is the use case that prompted me to ask this question in the first place.

Comment: There are likely equivalents in other SQL dialects, @LudovicAubert. A [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=STUFF+MySQL) showed me that MySQL has the function `INSERT()`: [What’s the MySQL Equivalent of STUFF() in SQL Server?](https://database.guide/whats-the-mysql-equivalent-of-stuff-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 5):

Using [`LEN()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with variable

```
DECLARE @Val AS VARCHAR (MAX) = 'CATCH ME IF YOU CAN';
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Val, 2, LEN(@Val));
```

or directly with `LEN()`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('CATCH ME IF YOU CAN', 2, LEN('CATCH ME IF YOU CAN'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RIGHT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function, combined with [`LEN()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
All you have to do is subtract from `LEN()` the number of chars that you want to exclude from the start of the string:

```
SELECT RIGHT('CATCH ME IF YOU CAN', LEN('CATCH ME IF YOU CAN') - 1)
```